# Need Suggestions For AutoSuggest For VB.NET ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autosuggest

To provide some context, I have a combobox that the user interacts with to select an insurance company. Unfortunately they don't require just the name; sometimes insurance companies have the same name, and the only way to distinguish between them is to use their address (eg a Medicare office in North Carolina vs. a Medicare office in South Carolina). What I've currently done is use the combobox's DrawItem event to draw a tooltip next to the ComboBox when the dropdown list is displayed. The list itself displays the insurance company names, but the tooltip will display the address of the currently selected company. The combobox is set to DropDownList, so it's impossible for them to pick anything but what's in the list.

Well, now I'm being told to change this. The users are no longer content to have to click the combobox or hit the arrow keys. They want comboboxes that they can type in and have an autosuggest list appear as they type. That's all well and good but this is where I'm running into a wall. My cute little scheme of using a tooltip can't work in that situation because the autosuggest list is a completely separate control. DrawItem doesn't touch it, and I can't find a way to custom draw the autosuggest list. The other problem is that autosuggest doesn't do duplicate entries, so even though I have two different insurance companies only one will appear in the list simply because they share the same name.

The only other idea I've had so far is to somehow scroll the dropdown list to the appropriate item upon the user pressing a key. But I can't figure out how to set the highlighted item in the dropdown list without setting selectedindex. If I use selectedindex, it goes ahead and replaces the text.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to proceed? Am I on the right track, or do am I trying too hard and need to do something else entirely?

Comment: Is this a windows form app or a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a text field where the user types in their text, and narrow the selection in the dropbox down based on that.  To get around the same-name-but-different-company problem, you could list the address of the company after the name in a parenthesis.  If the user types in a name that is invalid, put up an error/warning icon next to the text field.

To update the selection at runtime, you can add an event listener to the text field and query the current text to decide whether it is a valid prefix, or not.

Comment: I have actually tried something along these lines before elsewhere in my code, with pretty good success. The only problem is that I may be asked to leave in the combobox functionality to accommodate users who want or prefer to use that method.

Comment: I don't see where the problem is with the combobox functionality you mentioned

Comment: There isn't a problem, I was just thinking that I once the user has made their selection via the suggest box that I would then have to cycle back through the dropdown list and set selectedindex to whatever choice the user made. But now that I think about it, what does that really matter? Once they've made their selection they're unlikely to change it, and even if they do it's no huge loss if the selected index isn't up to date. I think I'm just overthinking things.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar at the company I'm at. To accomplish it, we utilize a web service through AJAX.

Essentially, you modify a standard textbox with an AJAX AutoCompleteExtender (ACE). This ace references a webservice (which I'll illustrate) that goes and gets the info the customer types in on the fly. It's pretty cool once it's up and running.

Here's an example:

.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInsuranceCompany" runat="server" TabIndex="520" 
      AutoComplete="Off"AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="asbSearch" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="aceInsuranceCompany" runat="server" CompletionSetCount="20"
       MinimumPrefixLength="0" OnClientShown="resetPosition" ServiceMethod="LookupData"
       ServicePath="~/WebLookUpService.asmx" TargetControlID="txtInsuranceCompany" UseContextKey="true">
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Something subtle is that you have to be sure you set the context key for your autocomplete extender, as well as create some functionality within your webservice to load your values (again, I'll illustrate).

.vb code-behind

```
 Dim yourhardcodedlist As New List(Of String)
 yourhardcodedlist.Add("Progressive")
 yourhardcodedlist.Add("State Farm")
 yourhardcodedlist.Add("USAA")
 WebLookUpService.AddLookupValues(txtInsuranceCompany.ID, yourhardcodedlist.ToArray)
 aceInsuranceCompany.ContextKey = public_var0 & ":" & public_var1 & ":" & txtInsuranceCompany.ID
```

Note that the "public_var0" "and public_var1" aren't mandatory. This is just illustrating how you could pass more information to your web service without actually passing it as a parameter (i.e. a colon-delimitted list, that you're web service function can parse out for use in a SQL statement or something).

Now for the webservice...(.asmx)

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebLookUpService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Function LookupData(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer,  ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
    'Construct SQL statement to pull from database
    'parsing the context key as necessary to construct your SQL statement (if necessary)
    'Dim somethingForSql As String = contextKey.Split(":")
    Dim suggestions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Try

        Using cnADO As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PublicSafetyServer").ToString)
            cnADO.Open()

            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("<YourSQLStatement>")         

            da.Fill(dt)

            Dim endRow As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            If endRow > count Then
                endRow = count
            End If

            For i As Integer = 0 To endRow - 1
                Dim des As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(field)
                Dim val As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(field)
                suggestions.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(des, val))
            Next
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Throw Error
    End Try

    suggestions.Sort()
    If suggestions.Count = 0 Then
        suggestions.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(noneFound, ""))
    End If
    Return suggestions.ToArray()
End Function
```

What's cool is that you can add values deliberately through 'yourhardcodedlist' that will combine with any values you pull via the web-service. This way, you can add values directly if you can't add values to the database.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a web-based application, it's a desktop program.

Comment: Matt, 

Bummer...haha, well maybe this will help you out: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/364616/Autosuggest-TextBox-from-database-column-in-Window

Comment: This makes me wonder.....was VB.NET a poor choice to do this in? I was the one who made that call. I'm working on a conversion from the program's old source code, which is in VB6. I thought that going to VB.NET would therefore be a logical progression, but maybe I should have done it in C++ or Java or something else entirely?

Comment: Did what was suggested at codeproject not work? Ya know, in Academia I was a strong proponent of C++ (and still am for Academic/ mission critical programs), but for business apps? .Net is awesome. I think your choice of language is alright.

Comment: Sadly no, it's not particularly helpful for my purposes. And I was asking if VB.NET was a good choice because it seems like it would have been a better choice had I been building this as a web application.

Comment: Oh, well, if you stick with vb.net you can still move everything over as a web app. Most windows form controls have an asp counterpart. Just an idea...remember, I'm pretty biased - I'm a vb.net web developer. If you do decide to depart from vb, I'd go java - c++ interfaces can be pretty tough (from what I've heard), but I don't use that everyday (so GrainOfSalt++).

Comment: Haha, I don't really plan on doing another migration. I've brought over too much to start all over again. It was more of a what-if question. But the really funny part is that we're thinking of eventually making our program into a web-based one. Until such time that we do get on that, I've been asked to make the program look as much like a web page as possible. Let me repeat that; I'm being asked to write a desktop application, but make it look like it's a web application. It's not what I would have decided, but then again I don't get paid to make those sorts of decisions.

Comment: Wow...I'm sorry about that bro - sounds rough. Well, I guess it's good you know the long term vision of the project. Something to shoot for in your off-time (especially since you'll be the one who'll have to support it anyways). Regards!